# Only one single item doesn't remove while trying to remove repeated items in Python. Why?

Tags: python

```
copyofnumbers = [1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 1]
copyofnumbers.sort()

for item in copyofnumbers:
    if (copyofnumbers.count(item) > 1):
        copyofnumbers.remove(item)

print(copyofnumbers)
```

I am trying to remove same items from the list. The above code removes all the repeated items but doesn't remove "1". What am I doing wrong ?

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

I expect the output should remove all the repeated items.

I expect the code to remove all the repeated items.

Comment: Do not *iterate* over a list you manipulate. By removing, you implicitly move the list one to the left over the cursor.

Comment: Tangentially related, you could identify unique values using pandas: `pd.unique(copyofnumbers)`

Answer (score 5):

You iterate over a list you manipulate. That means that each iteration the "cursor" progresses, but if you remove an element, then the list will thus be reduced, and as a result you make a hop of two.

Indeed, imagine the following situation:

```
1 2 2 2 2 4 5
  ^
```

Here the caret denotes the cursor of the iterator. You thus check if `4` occurs multiple times. You thus remove `4`, and Python will evidently remove the first one. Then you start the next iteration advancing the caret. So as a result the next iteration the situation looks like this:

```
1 2 2 2 4 5
    ^
```

So you "skipped" over the `2`. Maybe this does not look like a problem (yet). Since we still can remove `2`. But if we later remove the next `2`, the situation looks like:

```
1 2 2 4 5
      ^
```

So now we can no longer hope to remove `2`s.

That being said, using `.count(..)` and `.remove(..)` are usually not a good idea anyway. A `.count(..)` takes linear time to count the elements, and a `.remove(..)` takes, if you remove from the left, worst case linear time as well, making this a quadratic algorithm. Even if this thus worked, it would not be very efficient.

If the elements are hashable, and integers are hashable, we can simply convert these to a `set` (and back to a `list`, for example with `sorted`), like:

```
sorted(set(copyofnumbers))
```

This gives us:

```
>>> sorted(set(copyofnumbers))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```